# Cursor with Semi-Transparency / Anti-Aliasing

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to create a custom cursor with the following code:

```
BufferedImage cursor = new BufferedImage(30, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) cursor.getGraphics();
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawOval(0, 0, 26, 26);
jframe.getContentPane().setCursor(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
    cursor, new Point(13, 13), "cursor"));
```

Without Anti-Aliasing this looks really bad, but once I try to activate Anti-Aliasing, the pixels that are supposed to be semi transparent seem to become completely solid - as if the `JFrame` cursor cannot handle semi-transparency.

I've tried loading the `BufferedImage` from a `.png` file, but the results are the same.

*I do not want to draw the cursor manually on my canvas because it has a slight input lag compared to this method*.

All I want to do is have a Cursor that can support semi-transparency. 
Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This one is subtle (I've been stuck for a couple of years :) but I've cracked it today.

The cursor appears to only support on/off for transparency, so drawing first to a TYPE_INT_RGB image then copying that to a TYPE_INT_ARGB (then fixing the transparency) works.

Not sure if it's optimal, but it doesn't matter too much for small images like this.

```
        int size = 32;

        /*
         * we need two buffered images as the cursor only supports on/off for alpha
         * 
         * so we need to draw to an image without alpha support
         * then draw that to one with alpha support
         * then make "white" transparent
         */
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size, size,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        BufferedImage image2 = new BufferedImage(size, size,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2 = image2.createGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);


        // turn on anti-aliasing.
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4.0f)); // 4-pixel lines
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(new Color(0.5f, 0f, 0f));
        g.drawOval(3, 3, size-7, size-7);

        g2.drawImage(image,  0, 0, null, null);


        for (int y = 0 ; y < size ; y++) {
            for (int x = 0 ; x < size ; x++) {

                int rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);

                int blue = rgb & 0xff;
                int green = (rgb & 0xff00) >> 8;
                int red = (rgb & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                //int alpha = (rgb & 0xff000000) >> 24;

                if (red == 255 && green == 255 && blue == 255) {
                    // make white transparent
                    image2.setRGB(x, y, 0);
                }

            }
        }

        eraserCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
                image2, new Point(size / 2, size / 2), "eraserCursor");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code, to achieve translucent image, I use this snippet:

```
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.8f));
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
```

See whether it works for you...